# JCombobox auto search

Tags: java

I have a java program which keeps records of databases. I have made use of `JComboBox` for adding data to my db system. I have to initialize more than 10000 string into my `JComboBox`.  I have used keylistener to make my program auto search elements inside `JComboBox`. 
The problem is that it is taking a lot of time to search a single key. Is there a programming technique to make search faster with keylistener for more than 10000 string elements in `JComboBox`. Should I have to make use of multithreading to keylistener?

Comment: You can use [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/). This is opinion-based though so this question will not be very well received

Comment: To give advice, we'll need the code for your combo box and some details about the setup of the database from which the data should come. My suspicion is that you always transfer all 10000 records to the application instead of just getting the relevant ones by a database query, but without any code, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Generally:**

Never show so much elements at once into a List,Table,ComboBox etc. It makes the program lags and you spent a lot of memory.Maximum items to be shown per time must be <=300.Basically the comboBox its not so good idea a list or table will fit better.

**How?**

Every time the list shows 300 items,the user can use next button to load the next 300 from the database or previous button to load the 300 previous items.

**About Search:**

On every key pressed by user you search into database table you have for the 300 or less best fitting the result and then you add them into the List and ComboBox removing the previous items first.

**More about search:**
If you want you can retrieve all the items matching to search and use pagination for search results.